# Need info on periodic timers in linux

Tags: linux, timer

I need to send period heartbeat/message from a client process to server process to notify that client process is working fine and it's not stuck/hung in an infinite-loop OR unrecoverable condition. For periodic notification, I have used 'timer_create'/'timer_settime' API's to trigger periodic timers for every 5 seconds. With this,  what I have noticed is that, timers are triggered from kernel on behalf of process; hence even if that client process stuck in an infinite loop, I see timer is being triggered. Do we have any mechanism in Linux where we wait for notification periodically but notification is triggered from process rather than kernel.

Following is the code where main thread stuck in an infinite 'while' loop; still timers are being triggered.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CLOCKID CLOCK_REALTIME
#define SIG SIGUSR2

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    printf("Caught signal %d and\n", sig);
}

int main()
{
    timer_t timerid;
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec its;
    struct sigaction sa;


    /* Establish handler for timer signal */
    printf("Establishing handler for signal %d\n", SIG);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        perror("sigaction");

    /* Create the timer */
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid) == -1)
        perror("timer_create");

    printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

    /* Start the timer */
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 2 ;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
        perror("timer_settime");

     while (1) {
     }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

thanks in advance,
Shivanand

Comment: Signal handlers run in userspace in the context of your process. When the timer expires, the kernel makes your process interrupt the loop and run the handler. In userspace, you can't arrange such an interruption directly with the hardware. All signals go through the kernel.

Comment: thanks @PSkocik. I need to look for other approaches.